# How to check what permission failed in authorization in pyramid (pylons 2)?

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

I add a view for the forbidden view:

```
from pyramid.exceptions import Forbidden
config.add_view(forbidden_view, context=Forbidden)
```

which redirects to a log in screen.

But now i added some admin things which needed admin access, and I want to just show a "you don't have the permission" screen, how do I check for that in the forbidden view?

Comment: I'm not sure the Chris' answer is right. See the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448228/how-flexible-is-pyramids-auth-system/9450593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that information is lost when Pyramid raises a Forbidden error as the result of a permission denial.  There's an item in the TODO.txt to carry it along through the Forbidden error.