# How flexible is Pyramids auth system?

Tags: python, authorization, acl, pyramid

I am getting my feet wet working with the Pyramid framework (great framework), and I've come to the point of user authorization. I want to take advantage of the ACL to block users who are already logged in from visiting the registration page. Obviously, I could do this other ways, but I was wondering if there was any way to do this using tools in pyramid.

I know that by adding permissions to a view, users who do not meet the criteria are shown a forbidden view. In my case, I simply want to re route users who are already members away from views that  don't apply to them (registration, login, etc.).

I've tried `__acl__ = [(Deny, Authenticated, 'guest')]` to no avail, as it blocks the login page for all users.

Also, somewhat on another note, is there any way to dynamically change a route. I want the home page to be different for users who are logged in than it is for guests.

Comment: Pyramid's auth system is very flexible which is why it can be difficult to wrap your head around. I can't really tell you what you're doing wrong from that single snippet of an ACL, but I can tell you that if you turn on `pyramid.debug_authentication` it'll help tell what principals are returned from your authentication policy.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So I'm assuming that I am indeed headed in the right direction with the snippet that I put?

Comment: Also, when the forbidden view is called, is there a way to get the initial request that was called so that I can act accordingly and redirect to the correct page?

Comment: I added an answer that should address your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to investigate the principals that are being returned by your authentication policy to understand what's going on. It's easy to tell if you turn on `pyramid.debug_authorization` in your INI file. The authorization policy will compare the ACL found against the principals returned via `pyramid.security.effective_principals(request)`. If these do not match up, it should be clear what is going on.

The way to implement a form-based login would be (assuming Pyramid 1.3a9+):

```
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPSeeOther
from pyramid.security import authenticated_userid
from pyramid.view import forbidden_view_config

@forbidden_view_config()
def forbidden_view(request):
    if authenticated_userid(request):
        # user is already logged in, they are really forbidden
        return request.context # the forbidden 403 response

    url = request.route_url('login', _query={'came_from': request.path})
    return HTTPSeeOther(url)
```

That will add the `came_from` parameter to the URL as `request.GET['came_from']` in your login view. Of course if that isn't there you can just redirect them to the home screen after logging in.

Comment: I'm sorry Michael, but the acl I set still does not work, and I do not know why. Debug info says: `debug_authorization of url http://localhost:6543/register (view name u'' against context <occupeyed.security.RootFactory object at 0x3a62d50>): ACLDenied permission 'guest' via ACE '<default deny>' in ACL [('Allow', 'system.Authenticated', 'member'), ('Deny', 'system.Authenticated', 'guest')] on context <occupeyed.security.RootFactory object at 0x3a62d50> for principals ['system.Everyone']`

Comment: The code is: `__acl__ = [(Allow, Authenticated, 'member'),(Deny, Authenticated, 'guest')]`

Comment: When I use the guest permission `@view_config(route_name='register', renderer='register.mako', permission='guest')`, I get false positives (blocks unauthenticated users from registering).

Comment: Where do you allow unauthenticated users the 'guest' permission? I don't see anywhere *after* the `Deny` where you `(Allow, Everyone, 'guest')`.