# How to get the permission attached to the called view in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

In my forbidden view, I want to redirect all members to their dashboard if they visit a page for guests, and I want to redirect all guests to the login page if they visit a page for members. This is easy enough.

However, there are some cases where I need to throw an HTTPForbidden error which is not the cause of a failed permission and simply display the reason to the user. How can I determine whether an HTTPForbidden is a result of a failed permission or some other reason? I suppose I could do some weird stuff with `pyramid.security.has_permission` (haven't tried it yet), but there has to be an easier way.

An old question from 2011 where it was stated that this was on the to do list [How to check what permission failed in authorization in pyramid (pylons 2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916149/how-to-check-what-permission-failed-in-authorization-in-pyramid-pylons-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but what I'd try to do is to raise something else than `HTTPForbidden` in the places where you do this manually. You can even subclass `HTTPForbidden`:

```
class WeDontLikeYourFace(HTTPForbidden):
    pass

def my_view(context, request):
    if request['face'] != 'beautyful':
        raise WeDontLikeYourFace("go away")
```

Then you can register a custom view for your custom exception, or do some if/else stuff in the common view method registered for HTTPForbidden.

You can also add custom fields to your subclass to pass any information you need.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way, but I was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: Also, the logic `show_forbidden_page() if exception.raised_because_permission_failed() else manually_raised_exception_show_reason(exception.reason_msg)` is kinda not very explicit, feels like using an almost unintended side-effect of you raising the exception manually instead of doing it via Pyramid machinery.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you asked for but it may still help you.
The right answer to your question was already given: you'd better raise a specific exception that is more appropriate than `HTTPForbidden`.

But if you really want to change the behavior of your forbidden view depending on the missing permission that triggered the `HTTPForbidden` exception, you need to grab its name.
The name of the missing permission can be found inside the `HTTPForbidden` exception object in `HTTPForbidden.result.permission`.
But first, the `HTTPForbidden` exception needs to be passed as a context of your forbidden view.

For instance, here is how I use this in my webapps to inform the user why he cannot access a particular feature so that he can
ask a manager to re-configure ACL accordingly if appropriate.

```
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='/forbidden.mako')
def forbidden(context, request):
    return { 'required_permission': context.result.permission }
```

It works with pyramid 1.4.
I couldn't find anything in the documentation so I hacked this by debugging pyramid.
This is more a workaround than a clean solution.